# How to read data from a .txt file matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have this data from a radiation diagram of an antenna in a txt file:

[image]

And the text continues. As you see, the integer and decimal part of numbers are separated by commas, instead of points. Moreover, I don't need the first row since they aren't values. I have tried using this code:

```
file = fread('file.txt')
data = fread(file)
fclose(file)
```

However, all the data was in a vector, so I tried to visualise a little part of the file, writing `data = fread(file, [20,4])`. Nevertheless, the data was wrong, here's what I obtained:

[image]

I also tried with `fscanf` function, but I didn't work either. I'd like to open the entire file (without knowing the number of elements previously).

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to set culture for reading file in Matlab. My advice would be to convert commas to dots by any mean (external editor, with matlab, etc) before importing.

Comment: @Bentoy13 no built-ins, true, but easy enough work arounds available, even in MATLAB, see the dupe target. No need to resort to using other programs in between (although obtaining your data with decimal dot would be preferable of course)

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the delimiter in many data reading functions so it's not a comma, I find `readtable` the simplest:

```
T = readtable( 'file.txt', 'Delimiter', 'tab' );
```

It looks like your data is tab separated, so use the `'tab'` option. You could also use `'space'` or any given character.

Comma-formatted decimals can then be converted

```
c = T.Properties.VariableNames;
for ii = 1:numel(c)
    t.(c{ii}) = cellfun( @(x)str2double(strrep(x,',','.')), t.(c{ii}) );
end
```

Comment: That is a pretty good answer, but 'Delimiter' is mis-spelled

Comment: @TomF fixed typo